# How to insert new scene on pop stack in react native?

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-navigation, react-native-router-flux, react-navigation-stack

I am working on existing react native project and I want to find solution for pop action on navigation stack where I want to introduce new scene which is actually not on stack.

I have three different type of route based on state of user logged In, logged out or in locked state. So while user's app state is locked at that time on launch I am directing user to reset account page from launch scene.

Launch Scene -> Reset Account

But on back event of Reset Account, I want to show login page instead of Launch scene, but Login scene is not in stack as of now.

So how to insert new scene when user performs pop action ?

I am new to react native and I don't know how to modify navigation stack programmatically without performing any animation ?

In my project there is one package named `react-native-router-flux` to handle react navigation.

Any insight will be helpful.

Comment: Is there an issue with adding the login screen to your stack? If that is something you would consider the solution would be pretty simple and straight forward. I did not want to post the answer yet as it does not satisfy your question requirements of "inserting" the screen on pop

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create a `SwitchNavigator` between LaunchScreen and AccountStack

`AccountStack` is a `StackNavigator` that render both:

- LoginScreen.
- ResetAccountScreen. << This would be your initialRoute.